# Notice: Undefined index : line ,,,

Tags: php

I am running a PHP script, and keep getting errors like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\server\data\localweb\easy_ticket\admin\view_tickets.php on line 188
```

Line 188 looks like this:

```
if ($_GET["search"] || $_GET["filter"] && $_GET["f"]- && $_GET["sortby"]) {
```

After googling this issue I got this solution .. Using isset() 
The problem is that I cant visualize the way I apply this to the code .. @.@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should use `isset` construct separated by commas..

```
if (isset($_GET["search"],$_GET["filter"],$_GET["f"],$_GET["sortby"])
{
    // All variables have been set... do your coding stuff below
} else { echo "Some of the variables are not set"; }
```

Comment: I've been coding PHP for a few years now, and just now I realized you can add multiple parameters to `isset()`... I should of checked the doc's long ago. +1

Comment: Glad to be of help , Dave. However, this is not possible with `empty` though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ((isset($_GET["search"]) || isset($_GET["filter"])) && (isset($_GET["f"]) && isset($_GET["sortby"])) {
```